# install sql server driver on ubuntu

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to connect to sql server database which is placed on a remote server while my php code has been installed on an ubuntu server. I found that it needs to install sqlsrv driver or mssql driver before connecting. How can I install the requirement(s) in advanced?

Comment: What's the interface your PHP application uses for connection? PDO, ODBC, *mssql_\*()* functions directly, any other?

Comment: I'm using PDO driver

Answer (score 1):

Install PHP extension in OS: `apt-get install php5-sybase`, restart Apache or PHP-FPM (depending on your SAPI). Make sure the newly installed PDO driver is loaded (should be enabled automatically, check for output line *php5_invoke: Enable module pdo_dblib for [your SAPI here]*). This will also install all dependencies. Now you can use *mssql:* DSNs in PDO, as [presented in PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php).

There's [another PDO driver for MSSQL](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php), but it only works under Windows.

You can also use PDO with ODBC.